# Hibernate + JPA can't map different id for sub-class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

For reasons that were around before I got to this project, there are tables that are similar types but have different ID columns.

So, when I try this

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Element implements Serializable {
    public String title;
}

@Entity
public class PrimaryElement extends Element {
    @Id
    long pid;
}

@Entity
public class OtherElement extends Element {
    @Id
    long oid;
}
```

But then I get an obvious error

```
No identifier specified for entity: Element
```

Now, I can't very well put the ID in the Element class because they are obviously mapped to different columns.

I have tried various flavors of @Id and 'abstract' and @MappedSuperClass and so on..

I am at a complete loss.  Is there a way around this?

Any insights would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You might consider creating an abstract method called getId() in the parent class and use the @Column tag indicate the column name for the child elements.  There may be other ways to fix this.

Comment: Thanks for that, if I do that I receive: org.hibernate.mapping.UnionSubclass cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass

Answer (score 5):

You can either replace the @Entity and @Inheritance annotations of your Element class by @MappedSuperclass (this annotation is responsible for technical mappings and only PrimaryElement and OtherElement will be fully featured entities) or move the oid field with it's @Id annotation to the class Element and use the @AttributeOverride annotation in it's subclasses to modify the column names (in this case also the abstract class Element will be a fully featured entity).

```
@AttributeOverride(name="oid", column=@Column(name="primary_element_id"))
```

**UPDATE:**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Element implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private long id;
    public String title;
}

@Entity
@AttributeOverride(name="id", column=@Column(name="pid"))
public class PrimaryElement extends Element {
}

@Entity
@AttributeOverride(name="id", column=@Column(name="oid"))
public class OtherElement extends Element {
}
```

Comment: With @MappedSuperclass I always error out with: This class [class Element] does not define an IdClass

Comment: Have you also removed both class level annotations from the Element class and are the @Id annotated fields in the subclasses?

Comment: I have added @Id to the sub-classes removing it from the super class (as in the update) and that is when it is giving me this silly IdClass error.

Comment: Does your model only contain these three entities or additional @Entity annotated classes with relationships to the Element class?

Comment: It is only these 2 classes (with super class)

Comment: That looks like a bug in the JPA implementation. I've updated my answer one time again. Could you try if this solution works?